# How to caculate the two way ANOVA table "without" interaction term

Tags: anova

A bank likes to know whether the amount of loans granted to customs is associated with branch offices and customer groups(Groups A : high-risk customers;Group B: low -risk customers):Three replicates are recorded in each branch -group treatment combination.The mean values of branch-group combinations are given as below(thousands):

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{Branch A} & \text{Branch B} & \text{Branch C} & \text{Roll mean} \\
\hline
Group A & 80 & 60 & 70 &70 \\
Group B & 100 & 70 & 70 &80 \\
Column mean & 90 & 65 & 70 & 75
\end{array}
$$

You are given that the total sum of square is equal to 3750

1.Calculate the two way ANOVA table "without" interaction term

2.Calculate the two way ANOVA table "with" interaction term

The answer of 1. is

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 Source& \text{SS} & \text{df} & \text{MS} & \text{F} \\
\hline
Branch & 2100 & 2 & 1050 &12.25 \\
Group  & 450 & 1 & 450 &5.25 \\
Error & 1200 & 14 & 85.7143 & \\
total & 3750 & 17 & 
\end{array}
$$

But i don't know how two calculate when the source is SS and branch is equal to 2100.Can anyone explain it to me??

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few websites that walk through calculating ANOVA by hand eg, this [one](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/anova/how-to/two-way-anova/methods-and-formulas/methods-and-formulas/).

$SS_{source}=rb\sum_i (\bar{y_{i..}}-\bar{y_{...}})^2$

That is, sums of squares for source is equal to summing all the column means minus the grand mean squared, and then multiplying the number of rows and the number of replicates per cell.

Grand mean=(90+65+70)/3=75

The sum of the squares of the column means minus the grand mean=(90-75)^2+(65-75)^2+(70-75)^2=350

Number of replicates=3, number of rows=2

3*2*350=2100

Same thing for SS group, just flip the opposite from columns to rows

Grand mean=(80+70)/2=75

The sum of the squares of the row means minus the grand mean=(70-75)^2+(80-75)^2=50

Number of replicates=3, number of columns=3

3*3*50=450